# Operating in the end user's timezone with momentjs

Tags: javascript, timezone, timestamp, momentjs, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm in EDT and my end user is in PDT.  I'd like my WebApp to operate as if it's running in the end user's timezone (e.g. even if they travel it's to show the time back home).  The timestamps coming from the Java server are formatted to include the end user's timezone e.g. "Mon Oct 27 06:57:00 PDT 2014", and I also have the end user TZ string e.g. "America/Vancouver" in a config file.  I'm using native Date() and it's displaying the right time for the user, but I can't use it to compare times with times in the client.  I'm looking to change to moment.js, but I can't figure out how to get it to do what I want.  Basically, given the above timestamp, I want to be able to call m.hour() and get 6 back.  I also want to be able to get the day of the year in end user time (both "now" and for a timestamp), and see how far back the last timestamp is from the current time, in minutes.  Here is my failed attempt:

```
var d = "Mon Oct 27 06:57:00 PDT 2014";
var ds = d.split(/ /).slice(1).join(' '); // eat "Mon "

var m = moment.tz(ds, "MMM D HH:mm:ss Z YYYY", "America/Vancouver");

alert("" + m.hour()); // 23 ???  Want "6"!

var n = moment.tz("America/Vancouver");
var df = n.diff(m, 'minute');
alert(m.format() + "\n" + n.format() +
      "\n" + df + " minutes ago");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/up628qbq/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a lower-case `z` in the format string instead of the upper-case `Z`.  That will match the time time zone abbreviation characters.

Note that this won't actually interpret the abbreviation as a particular offset.  This is primarily because abbreviations can be ambiguous.  ([There are 5 different meanings of "CST"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)).  Because of this, some values during a [DST fall-back transition](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) may be interpreted incorrectly.

For example, in the Pacific time zone, there are two instances of 1:00 AM on November 2 2014.  The first is in PDT (-7) , and second is in PST (-8).  Even though you provided an abbreviation, moment *won't* use it to disambiguate.  If you want to be certain of which instance you are working with, you would need a numeric time zone offset to be included and parsed with `Z`.

Also, you can use `ddd` for the weekday name instead of splitting and slicing.

Comment: I also reported this [as an issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/144).

Comment: Thanks!!  Would it be better if I replaced the "PDT" with "America/Vancouver" before parsing?

Comment: Nah, that wouldn't help.  Probably would make thing worse since the time zone is normally passed as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Matt!  I don't have enough reputation to "vote up", so I have made the changes you recommend (remove `split` and add `ddd` format, change `Z` to `z`) in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/up628qbq/1/